# Can elementary OS be installed on a laptop that you can't disable Secure Boot?

Tags: system-installation, boot

Can elementary OS be installed on a laptop that you can't disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Is it ARM PC ?..

Comment: We have signed certificates for secure boot, so you should be able to. As for what @Ravan said, elementary does not currently come in ARM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install elementary OS with secure boot. During installation, I was partitioning the drive; it recognized that I was in secure boot mode and noticed that I did not have an EFI partition. I repartitioned it with an EFI parition (mounted at /boot/efi) and then elementary OS installed just fine.